# Kotlin + Spring AliasFor

Tags: java, spring, kotlin

I've been trying to use Springs `@AliasFor` annotation in a Kotlin project but it seems that the annotation on the annotation parameter isn't visible at runtime (hence it's not picked up by Spring).

For example:

```java
@RequestMapping(method = arrayOf(RequestMethod.POST))
annotation class PostMapping(
    @get:AliasFor(annotation = RequestMapping::class, attribute = "value")
    vararg val value: String = arrayOf())
```

And...

```java
// Returns empty array instead of array with the @AliasFor annotation
PostMapping::class.java.methods[0].annotations
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's a bug in Kotlin, which is not fixed at the moment: [KT-11475](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11475).

Comment: In the meantime you can write this one class in Java.

Comment: Thanks for the info!

Comment: This problem is fixed now, can use the `@get:` use-site target.

Answer (score 1):

Issue seems to has been fixed within scope of [KT-25287](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-25287) i.e. snippet from question should work for *Kotlin 1.3+*.